# Establish a term indicating that a comment will be deleted shortly by the author

Tags: discussion

I understand that comments in the Q & A should add value to the overall post. As stated in the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), they should request clarification, leave constructive criticism or provide other relevant info.

However, not all questions are well structured and clearly defined, at least at first. So I find myself sometimes engaged in a commenting back and forth with the OP as an answer is being developed. Multiple updates to the answer result.

Yesterday and today I was engaged in a prolonged commenting session with an OP where probably 90% of the comments were about logistics and did not add value to the question. Comments like: *Do you see what I'm talking about in Chrome Dev Tools?*, *Are you on a Mac or a PC?* and *Let's just get this done quickly. Call me.  XXX-XXX-XXXX*.

So my question is:

> Before the powers that be jump in to admonish the commenting parties,
>   or simply delete comments altogether, is it worth creating a term that
>   tells everybody that a comment is just temporary and will be deleted shortly? Maybe something like [wbd]?

So a comment like: *"I need to leave my computer for a while. I haven't forgotten about your question. I'll respond again in about an hour."*, which obviously adds no value to the question but may still help in crafting a good answer, could end with *[wbd]*, which would indicate to SO moderators that the comment is recognized as having no material value and "will be deleted" shortly by the author.

Just off the bat, I see several potential benefits of something like [wbd]:

- a free flowing conversation can ensue and possibly lead to improved editing of questions and better answers
- the human urge to express appreciation and say "thank you" doesn't have to be completely suppressed
- less moderator time could be spent deleting "bad" comments.
- eliminates the guesswork from moderators when it comes to comments that may be "on-the-fence" (assuming this is ever an issue)
- the system can automatically delete all [wbd] comments that have been around for, let's say, more than 48 hours.
- sometimes I want to follow up with an OP (who has accepted my answer or has not accepted any answer) to offer support. With [wbd] I could simply jump back to my answer and leave this comment: *If you have any questions about my answer or need assistance just leave a comment [wbd].* I could then totally forget about this comment because it will be automatically deleted in 48 hours.
- creates a more robust and efficient system of self-policing at the ground level, which preserves resources at higher levels

Is [wbd] an idea worth exploring? An asinine suggestion? I'm open to your feedback.

Comment: Does a comment saying you will respond in a few hours provide any value at all in the first place?

Comment: I usually just don't leave a comment to that affect, then respond in a few hours.

Comment: Your example seems about tagging *somewhat redundant* comments. Or is this primarily about *limiting their longetivity* and an automatism for that?

Comment: (Btw, I remember way back there was a bit of a trend to add `[accept rate, accept rate]` to comments for easier deletion… Something less gaudy may or may not make sense perhaps.)

Comment: @mario: It's about opening up the comment section to less restrictive discussion that may lead to better answers, improved editing and a more amiable environment. And then having a recognized system (starting at the user level) for filtering out all comments that have no enduring value.

Comment: I agree there's a few comment styles that lie somewhere between advisory and inquisiting more details, but distract from the question when stale. Actually I've been pondering this too (because too lazy to clean them up myself). Some implicit timeout could be useful - and if posters won't respond timely / ignore them, there's little harm in having them stripped implicitly. → The question of course is, *when/how* such a feature would lead to cleaner Q&As instead of encouraging chattiness.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see how leaving such a comment accomplishes anything useful. At most, it tells the op they can stop waiting for more comments, but for all you or they know someone else may come along and continue the discussion without you.

It's certainly possible to continue the discussion at separate times, you don't both have to be active at the same time for a discussion in comments to be effective.

Answer (score 3):

> the system can automatically delete all [wbd] comments that have been
>   around for, let's say, more than 48 hours.

There is a user script over on Stack Apps for [self-destructing comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/6316/self-destructing-comments/6333). It even tags comments created with it as self-destructing comments.

> a free flowing conversation can ensue...

They'd probably want that to happen in a chat room instead of in the comments. In fact, after a certain number of comments you get prompted to take it to chat.

As for moderator workload, I honestly can't speak to that. Do moderators waste a lot of time cleaning up obsolete comments? I usually only see/hear about comments getting flagged if they cause a problem by being there, besides being "noise".

Comment: The people who may need to use [wbd] most are those with the least experience on the site. Chat is only available once you have 20 rep. My question was sparked by a very long commenting session with a new user, and chat never kicked in.

Comment: @Michael_B then, with the least experience on the site, how do you assume they will know what [wbd] is? They have trouble understanding the base purpose of the site, or how to edit their question... but they'll get [wbd] in comments? I don't think it's going to happen

Comment: @Patrice, the answerer would know what [wbd] is. That's all that would be needed for the new OP to learn it. Which I submit would be an improvement to the current system, where most new users learn about commenting rules "the hard way'.

Comment: @michael_b not unless the OP asks "why do you put that?" and gets an answer. Creating even more noise. I don't say we should keep comments indefinitely. But the keyword seems clunky

Comment: @BSMP usually the mods seem to lean towards more policing of comments instead of less, from what I've read anyway.

Comment: @Patrice, not an issue in my view. Maybe even an improvement. It's a simple one-line response to the OP. Or the answerer could be proactive. *Hi, and welcome to SO! If you notice that I put [wbd] after a comment that means it will be deleted shortly. We prefer to keep only comments that can help future readers.*

Comment: _Chat is only available once you have 20 rep._ - That doesn't mean you're supposed to chat in the comments instead. If it's really taking a lot of extended conversation to get all of the info needed to answer the question, it should be flagged as unclear or as "debugging question lacks necessary info" .

Answer (score 0):

I think that the guidelines are that such logistic comments which don't add value to the post are supposed to be done in a chat.

Writing logic comments only to delete them later on will probably make the comment stream unreadable once the logistic comments are deleted.

It is probably pretty unsafe for you to leave your phone number in the comments, even if you plan on deleting the comment later.